# ¿Cómo comparar String con una Lista?

Tags: java, poo

El tema es que tengo un archivo que contiene los países del mundo en formato txt. Ejemplo:

```
"Albania""Albania""355"
"Alemania""Germany""49"
"Algeria""Algeria""213"
```

Lo que quiero es que el usuario vaya a hacer consultas en ese archivo buscando solamente por país, y si hay coincidencia pues escribir esa misma línea en otro texto que solamente va a contener el resultado de las consultas.
El problema que hay es que yo creo una lista, y la relleno con los datos entrados por teclado, pero cuando llego al punto donde pretendo copiar el String que contiene la línea del archivo txt con mi Lista, no me sale nada porque el compilador no entra a la condición if.

Os dejo el código:

```
public class buscarContenido {


    public void buscar(){
        System.out.println("\t\tLBienvenido al programa de consultas\n");
        //Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\archivoTXT\\coco.txt"));
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\archivoTXT\\kiwi.txt"));
            System.out.println("Introduce el nombre del pais al que quieres buscar:\n");
            String lee;
            String[] b = new String[10];

            ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();


            for(int i=0;i<=0;i++){
                Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

                b[i] = s.next(); 
                lista.add(b[i]);
            }

            lista.forEach(System.out::println);

            do{
                lee = br.readLine();

                if((lista.contains(parts))){
                    bw.write(lee); 
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.flush();
                    System.out.println(lee);
                }

               }while(lee!=null);}
                bw.close();
                br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(buscarContenido.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List.contains` y similares lo que hacen es que van llamando al método `equals()` de los distintos elementos y según el valor operan; por ejemplo `contains()` devuelve `true` si al menos hay un elemento `x` tal que `x.contains(valorBuscado)` devuelve `true`.

Así que la cuestión no es comparar listas con `String`, sino `String`s con `String`s. Tú simplemente lees toda la línea, de forma que los `String`s que almacenas son:

- Primer `String`: `"Albania""Albania""355"`
- Segundo `String`: `"Alemania""Germany""49"`
- ...

Obviamente, `"Alemania""Germany""49"` no es lo mismo que `Alemania`, así al comparar los dos `String`s, `equals` devuelve `false`.

Tienes dos opciones:

- En vez de usar `contains`, iterar sobre la lista y ver, para cada `String`, si contiene el valor que buscas (método `indexOf`).
- Al leer los datos del archivo, sacar la cadena que vas a usar para buscar y guardarla en la lista, de forma que al hacer el `equals` por el valor que buscas devuelva `true` y `contains` también devuelva `true`.

Comment: He iterado con un for pero dentro del bucle no sé como implementar el indexOff porque no me queda claro su función dentro de mi código

Comment: Vale muchísimas gracias, ya lo pillo.+1